# Person name + 的

Tags: colloquial-language, slang, grammar

In a short story I'm reading I found this dialogue:

> 「やりたいことがあるって、いいよね。どうしたらみつけられるのかな」
>
> 雅世{まさよ}はきょとんとした。
>
> 「**藤岡{ふじおか}的**にはぁ、やりたいことがないヤツのほうが不思議なんですけど?」
>
> 藤岡的、が出てしまった。雅世は自分のことを苗字で呼ぶ。

I'm confused about 藤岡的, since 藤岡 is the surname of one of the characters, as confirmed by the last line; it's like it's making the name "fujioka-ical/ish", but I'm not sure what's supposed to mean and I wasn't able to find anything about it; my best guess, it's something like "In my book", "Fujioka thinks that", "What's like Fujioka is thinking that" and so on: Fujioka is saying that according to her opinion it's more strange not having anything one wants to do, instead that having something.

I don't think it matters, but I'm not sure also about 「なんですけど? 」: my guess, 「けど」 leaves the sentence open, softening it and/or asking the other opinion; and the question mark softens the statement by making it a question, almost like Fujioka is not really saying people who don't know what they want to do are strange, rather she is asking about it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

～的には is a way to say "～ly speaking, ...", "～-wise, ..." or "in terms of ～".

- **個人的には**気にしていない。
  **Personally**, I don't care.
- **金銭的には**困っているが幸せだ。
  I'm in trouble **money-wise**, but I'm happy.
- **世界的には**大きな問題だ。
  It's a big problem **worldwide**.

This type of 的 is just a suffix to turn a noun into a na-adjective (It's like '-(i)al' as in person**al**, financ**ial**, glob**al**, etc.).

In slangy speech, this is extended to personal pronouns or proper nouns. It's like "from the standpoint of ～", but sounds much more slangy and casual.

- **僕的には**大丈夫です。
  **Personally**, I'm fine with it.
- **君的には**どうなの?
  What do ***you*** think?
- **藤岡的にはぁ**、やりたいことがないヤツのほうが不思議なんですけど?
  But **if you ask me**, I don't understand someone who doesn't know what they want to do.
  <sub>(The speaker is 藤岡 herself. See [this](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/66380/5010).)</sub>