# What is "ぷれせんとふぉーゆーさん" exactly referring to？

Tags: usage, expressions, song-lyrics

I was looking at the lyrics of a song and there's a part of it that says the following:

```
いびつな形でもつたわるかい？
昔からかわらない愛
きっとかわりはしない
ぷれせんとふぉーゆーさんたから
そんなの信じてたんだなー
「まま」はいなくて
「ぱぱ」だけぱぱすき
なんてゆあないだけ
```

I know ぷれせんとふぉーゆーさん should be プレセントフォーユーさん since it translates to "Present for you san", but , I'm having troubling interpreting this. Is it a way to
call someone that gives presents? Is it a phrase that you say when you give a present to someone? I don't find any information about it on the internet or translators.

Comment: Shouldn't it be ぷれ**ぜ**んと?

Comment: I found it as せ in the original transciption but yeah I think ぜ is the correct way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not -さん.

> ぷれせんとふぉーゆー、さんたから
> Present for You, From Santa (Claus).

I think it's intentionally written in all-hiragana to [emphasize the childishness](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/15108/5010) of this idea.

Comment: Yeah, It makes sense now! Thank you so much!

Comment: Wouldn't it normally be より here rather than から at the end?

Comment: @Героямслава If this is a letter, yes, より is more common, but since this is a gift, both are fine.